# Error connecting to posgresql database using pg on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, psql, pg

I've got a PostgreSQL database, definitely existing because I can connect to it and make SQL query using psql.

However, when I try to connect with node.js, using the `pg` client, I've got an error saying that the database does not exist.

Here is how the connection work:

```
var pg = require('pg');
const connection = new pg.Client({
   host: 'localhost',
   port: 5432,
   database: 'camino',
   user: 'postgres',
  password: 'postgres'
})

connection.connect();
```

And here is the error I obtained: 
[image]

In english: `The database **camino** does not exist`.

Can you enligthen me on this error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have created the database camino by using the create table syntax found here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createdatabase.html

If you have already done that, Postgresql starts with 3 default databases called: postgres, template0 and template1. Have you tried connecting to the default postgres database and confirmed that it works?

Comment: I tried to do so, and managed to connect to those database. I then recreated my database but still didn't manage to connect to it. I've also checked if the user and password I used to connect to the default postgres db are the same that the one I used to create my db...

Comment: Ok, I uninstalled / reinstalled postgres and it worked.. Still don't know from where this error is coming from however.